# Retrieve JSON Object Key Values using SED command

Tags: json, ubuntu, sed

I have a JSON like below coming from curl command and it is present in a output.txt file. I want to retreive the JIRA status, here it is "In Progress"

```
{
     "self": "https://jira.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/1",
     "fields": {
        "status": {
            "self": "https://jira.com/jira/rest/api/2/status/10170",
            "description": "", 
            "name": "In Progress",
            "id": "10170" 
        }
    }
}
```

I have a restriction to use only sed . I tried like below it does not work . I am not sure how to navigate to the name value. can you please suggest to print JIRA status

```
sed -n 's|.*"fields":{"status":{"name":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p'  output.txt
```

Comment: jq seems like a better fit for dealing with JSON (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: The docker image does not work with jq unfortunately. I cannot change the docker right now and it works only with sed

Comment: How about `sed -nE '/"name":/ s/.*"(.+)".*/\1/p'` or `awk -F'"' '/"name":/{print $4}'` assuming only one line will match when searching for `"name":`

Comment: Try `sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*"name": "\(.*\)",/\1/p' file`, see https://ideone.com/VuKvrY. Do you really need to check for `fields":{"status"` presence?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Not really

Comment: If the JSON-structure is formatted like the example (with linebreaks), and the status is always in the field "name" another option is grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*"name": "\(.*\)",/\1/p' output.txt
# With GNU sed:
sed -n 's/^\s*"name":\s*"\(.*\)",/\1/p' output.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VuKvrY)

*Details*:

- `n` - suppresses default line output
- `^\s*"name":\s*"\(.*\)",` - matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `"name":` - a literal string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `\(.*\)` - a POSIX BRE capturing group matching any text up to
  - `",` - the last occurrence of `",` (they are at the end of the targeted line anyway).
- `\1` - replaces the whole match with Group 1 value
- `p` - only prints the replacement result.

With a GNU `sed`, you can also use the `-z` option to read the file as a single string and then use a more specific pattern:

```sh
sed -z 's/.*"fields":\s*{\s*"status": {.*\s*name": "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' output.txt
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/Lxw7GE).

It does something very close to [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fyyjTP/1).